# apache tomcat on Google cloud Instance

Tags: connection, google-cloud-platform, tomcat8, centos7

I have installed java and apache tomcat on my Google cloud instance and have started the tomcat but when I try to connect to my instance from my browser on port 8080 or 8443 I cannot connect it. I should see the apache tomcat's welcome page right? Can someone plz help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure firewall to allow those ports. 
The best option for your use case would be to use Google Cloud Launcher. 
https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/tomcat.

It should give you an external IP with HTTP and HTTPS tomcat ports open 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the details of your instance and click on **edit**.
Now in the firewalls section and check **Allow HTTP traffic**.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mExsW.png)